# Simple PyQt5 counting GUI

Tags: python, gui, pyqt

I just began learning how to use signals and slots in PyQt5, and so I made a cute (pun intended) little program to display just one button. When the button is pressed a thread is spawned which will count from 0 to 99 and display the current count onto the button. However, when the button is counting, the program will not allow the user to spawn *another* thread.

I am about to actually use my knowledge for a much heavier task, and I wanted to know if there was an easier way to do what I did. Or, perhaps my way is not very efficient? Thanks in advance!

```
import threading
import sys
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Application(QMainWindow):
    counter = pyqtSignal(str)
    counting = False

    def __init__(self):
        super(Application, self).__init__()

        self.button = QPushButton()
        self.button.setText('99')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.startCounting)
        self.counter.connect(self.button.setText)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)

    def startCounting(self):
        if not self.counting:
            self.counting = True
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.something)
            thread.start()

    def something(self):
        for x in range(100):
            self.counter.emit(str(x))
            time.sleep(.01)
        self.counting = False



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Application()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have never used PyQt, so I am asking for my own edification: why do you use a `pyqtSignal` instead of just setting the text directly?

Comment: @zondo because its 'good practice' to let the main thread handle anything GUI related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me!

super minor nits:

```
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.something)
        thread.start()
```

only uses the `thread` variable once, so you might as well do:

```
        threading.Thread(target=self.something).start()
```

Also, the only thing you use from `threading` is `Thread` so you might as well change your import to:

```
from threading import Thread
```

and then it can be just:

```
Thread(target=self.something).start()
```

...but again, these are super minor things!  It looks good to me; I may have to look at pyQT again :)

Answer (score 1):

since you already used signals/slots mechanism in your program you can easily replace python thread mechanism with QThread() and make it use separate Counter() object to divide program into separate logical blocks:

```
# Similar to threading.thread(target=self.counter.start)
self.counterThread = QThread()
self.counter = Counter()
self.counter.moveToThread(self.counterThread)
self.counterThread.started.connect(self.counter.start)
```

Where the Counter() class (often named as Worker() class) is:

```
class Counter(QObject):
    '''
    Class intended to be used in a separate thread to generate numbers and send
    them to another thread.
    '''

    newValue = pyqtSignal(str)
    stopped = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    def start(self):
        '''
        Count from 0 to 99 and emit each value to the GUI thread to display.
        '''

        for x in range(100):
            self.newValue.emit(str(x))
            time.sleep(.01)
        self.stopped.emit()
```

By using this approach you can even modify Counter() object to receive some data from the GUI on-the-fly and react accordingly.

Another minor thing is that "from package import *" was used. Usually it is considered a bad practice since you import all the contents of the package. In this case all QtCore and QtWidgets modules were imported which is ~2/3 of the PyQt5 package itself I believe))) It is more verbose but much better to use:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QFrame, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread
```

or:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
...
self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
```

That way you and other code readers always know which object belongs to which package as well.

Here is the complete code rewritten according to those notes:

```
'''
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138992/simple-pyqt5-counting-gui
'''

import sys
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QFrame, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread

class Counter(QObject):
    '''
    Class intended to be used in a separate thread to generate numbers and send
    them to another thread.
    '''

    newValue = pyqtSignal(str)
    stopped = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    def start(self):
        '''
        Count from 0 to 99 and emit each value to the GUI thread to display.
        '''

        for x in range(100):
            self.newValue.emit(str(x))
            time.sleep(.01)
        self.stopped.emit()


class Application(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # Configuring widgets        
        self.button = QPushButton()
        self.button.setText('99')
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)

        # Configuring separate thread
        self.counterThread = QThread()
        self.counter = Counter()
        self.counter.moveToThread(self.counterThread)

        # Connecting signals
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.startCounting)
        self.counter.newValue.connect(self.button.setText)
        self.counter.stopped.connect(self.counterThread.quit)
        self.counterThread.started.connect(self.counter.start)


    def startCounting(self):
        '''
        Start counting if no other counting is done.
        '''

        if not self.counterThread.isRunning():
            self.counterThread.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Application()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Keep up the good work and best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I spent the day researching how threading should be done in PyQt5 for one of my own projects and found that a lot of the documentation was incorrect, including official documentation.

This was the best documentation we were able to find: [Here](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/concurrent-execution/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/)
[Here](https://github.com/Givo29/pyqt5-threading) is a proof of concept example I came away with and later implemented.

Basically you have a `Thread` class where the code to be executed is in the run function:

```
class Thread(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Thread, self).__init__()     
        self.signal = Signals()    

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        result = "Some String"
        self.signal.return_signal.emit(result)
```

This makes a call to a `Signal` class that will store the signal as a subclass of `PyQt5.QtCore.QObject`:

```
class Signals(QObject):
    return_signal = pyqtSignal(str)
```

Then the basic `Application` class that creates an instance of a `PyQt5.QtCore.QThreadPool` in the `__init__` function and creates and calls the thread in `clickCheckbox` which sends the return signal to `function_thread`:

```
class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.title='Hello, world!'
            self.left=2100
            self.top=500
            self.width=640
            self.height=480
            self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
            self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
            self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
            self.setGeometry(self.left,self.top,self.width,self.height)
            checkbox = QCheckBox('Check Box', self)
            checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self.clickCheckbox)
            self.show()

    def clickCheckbox(self):
        thread = Thread()
        thread.signal.return_signal.connect(self.function_thread)
        self.threadpool.start(thread)

    def function_thread(self, signal):
        print(signal)
```

Initialising Application Window:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
        app=QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex=App()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Applying all this, here is what I would suggest you do to your code:**

```py
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Signal(QObject):
    signal = pyqtSignal(str)

class Thread(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self, counting):
        super(Thread, self).__init__()
        self.counting = counting
        self.signal = Signal()

    def run(self):
        for x in range(100):
            self.signal.signal.emit(str(x))
            time.sleep(.01)
        counting = False
        self.signal.signal.emit(str(counting))

class Application(QMainWindow):
    counting = False

    def __init__(self):
        super(Application, self).__init__()

        self.button = QPushButton()
        self.button.setText('99')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.startCounting)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()

    def startCounting(self):
        thread = Thread(self.counting)
        thread.signal.signal.connect(self.something)
        self.threadpool.start(thread)

    def something(self, signal):
        if signal == "False":
            print("Counting is Complete")
        else:
            print(signal)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Application()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```